# Show that the set of attractor is an open set

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $$U\colon=\{ A\in M_{2}(\mathbb{R}): x'=Ax \mbox{ such that  this define a attractor focus } \}$$

Show that $U$ is an open set.

My approach: We know that, a linear system $x'=Ax$ is an attractor iff all his eigenvalues of $A$, has negative real part. Since, $A\in M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and the root of characteristic polynomial are the eigenvalues, we have that $$p_{A}(x)=x^2-tr(A)+det(A)\implies\lambda_{1,2}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(tr(A)\pm\sqrt{(tr(A))^2-4det(A)}\right)$$

Now, I wanna write, the set $U$ has the preimage of open set, by a continuous function (since, this imples that $U$ is an open set). Furthemore, the problem talk about, "attractor focus". Any idea, will be appreciated! Thanks!